# Google Hangouts integration with Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I am creating a `WordPress plugin` which starts `hangouts on air` and I have hangout title. searched the internet but couldn't found anything.

> 1. I want to parse my title (It should be hangout title),
> 2. Get video ID programmatically (Show video id on my web page).
> 3. Get hangouts link programmatically.

How can I do this? No idea for creating this. Any answers will be appreciated.